# Dynamically insert class in <li> with ViewBag for Navigation, with a sub level depedancy (MVC)

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-lists, viewbag

I'm a big fan of the TFS website layout and design, and I've taken up on myself to recreate the layout as a little test in ASP.NET MVC.

Now I'm trying to recreate the navigation bar and it's a 2 tiered horizontal navigation bar (see below for picture), and I can't seem to get this working correctly, and I've resorted to using the ViewBag to apply the active class on the selected action.

See the following code to see what I have at the moment,

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="@(ViewBag.TopTabIndex == 0 ? "active" : "")"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li class="@(ViewBag.TopTabIndex == 1 ? "active" : "")"><a href="#reportingsuite" data-toggle="tab">Reporting Suite</a></li>
    <li class="@(ViewBag.TopTabIndex == 2 ? "active" : "")"><a href="#pivotgrid" data-toggle="tab">Pivot Grid Analysis</a></li>
    <li class="@(ViewBag.TopTabIndex == 3 ? "active" : "")"><a href="#reportserver" data-toggle="tab">Report Server Management</a></li>
    <li class="@(ViewBag.TopTabIndex == 4 ? "active" : "")"><a href="#datawarehouse" data-toggle="tab">Data Warehouse</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now, thats working fine, its applying active on the tab's I have but I now need to create a sub level to match the navigation I'm trying to accomplish, but currently stuck on doing this.

Can anyone point me in a direction of what way i should go to achieve the correct logic i need to create a sub-level dependant navigation system while using the viewbag to set it as active?

My thoughts on this are something like,

```
<div class="divide-nav">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="@(ViewBag.TopTabIndex == 0 ? "active" : "")"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
            <li class="@(ViewBag.TopTabIndex == 1 ? "active" : "")"><a href="#reportingsuite" data-toggle="tab">Reporting Suite</a></li>
            <li class="@(ViewBag.TopTabIndex == 2 ? "active" : "")"><a href="#pivotgrid" data-toggle="tab">Pivot Grid Analysis</a></li>
            <li class="@(ViewBag.TopTabIndex == 3 ? "active" : "")"><a href="#reportserver" data-toggle="tab">Report Server Management</a></li>
            <li class="@(ViewBag.TopTabIndex == 4 ? "active" : "")"><a href="#datawarehouse" data-toggle="tab">Data Warehouse</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sub-nav">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="@(ViewBag.TopTabIndex == 0.1 ? "active" : "")"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a></li>
            <li class="@(ViewBag.TopTabIndex == 1.1 ? "active" : "")"><a href="#reportingsuite" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a></li>
            <li class="@(ViewBag.TopTabIndex == 2.2 ? "active" : "")"><a href="#pivotgrid" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a></li>
            <li class="@(ViewBag.TopTabIndex == 3.3 ? "active" : "")"><a href="#reportserver" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a></li>
            <li class="@(ViewBag.TopTabIndex == 4.5 ? "active" : "")"><a href="#datawarehouse" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

But, I need some logic to tell the main navigation level to display the sub level tabs based upon the integer in the ViewBag.

Please see the image below for an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

Two Tiered Navigation Bar:

[image]

Comment: You need two ViewBag items, one for the main nav-bar, and one for the sub-nav.

Comment: Thanks, how would i go about hiding the sub level menu options per the top level navigation choice?

For example, if i chose About, i would only want to see overview of the about page and not the overview of the home page as well, thanks.

Comment: It's so simple. Use an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the integer part of number is specify the first level nav and number after point specify second level of nav. So if ViewBag.TopTabIndex is 0.2 the first li of first level nav and the scond li of second level nav will be active:

```
 <div class="divide-nav">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="@(Math.Floor(ViewBag.TopTabIndex) == 0 ? "active" : "")"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-nav">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="@(ViewBag.TopTabIndex == 0.1 ? "active" : "")"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a></li>
                    <li class="@(ViewBag.TopTabIndex == 0.2 ? "active" : "")"><a href="#reportingsuite" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, i'm trying your method with the Math.Floor and i'm recieving the following error:

The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Math.Floor(decimal)' and 'System.Math.Floor(double)

I've tried declaring it as an decimal by putting m behind 0.1 and 0.2 but no luck!

Comment: It is because you are giving ViewBag.TopTabIndex an integer number like 0 or 1. But you should give a float number to it like 0.1

Comment: If you still have this problem post here the line you are valuating ViewBag.TopTabIndex.